# Is there a way to check if the RecyclerView class is empty outside the Adapter class?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I was building this simple Notepad application. All the notes are hosted within a RecyclerView and there's a button that can be used for deleting all the notes. Now, when the user presses the button to delete all the notes, an AlertDialog pops up. The thing is, this AlertDialog pops up even when there are no notes present within the application. I wanted to stop that. The AlertDialog should pop up only when there are notes present.

I was wondering if there was some way through which I could get the RecyclerView size within the Activity from the Adapter class. I thought this would be the best way to go about achieving this objective. If there are any better ways, by all means, do let me know.

Here are the respective classes:

**NotesActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.R;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.databinding.ActivityNotesBinding;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.model.Constants;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.model.INotesActivity;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.room.NotesDatabase;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.room.NotesEntity;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.viewmodel.NotesActivityViewModel;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * The NotesActivity is the primary activity in the entire applications.
 * This activity starts up and shows the user all the notes that have been created or the facility to add a new note using the floating action button.
 * All the notes that have been created using this application and short details associated with them show up in the RecyclerView.
 * The user can click on any of these notes to view the complete details of the note.
 */
public class NotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, INotesActivity {

    private ActivityNotesBinding activityNotesBinding;
    private NotesActivityViewModel notesActivityViewModel;

    /*The onCreate method is the first method that is executed when the application starts up.
     * Usually, in this method, such functions are executed that are to be performed only once.
     * In this method, I've defined two other methods to be executed as soon as the application starts up and that are to be executed only once.
     * The initializeDatabase() method is used to create an instance of the RoomDatabase.
     * An application context is used because we want to use the same instance throughout the context of the application.
     * The initializeViewModel() is used to create an instance of the ViewModel class associated with this activity.
     * This ViewModel will be used to handle any configuration changes. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activityNotesBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_notes);
        initializeDatabase();
        initializeViewModel();
    }

    /*The onStart() is the next method executed after the onCreate() callback method.
     * In this method, two methods are executed, namely the setOnClickListenerMethod() and the setObserverMethod().
     * The setOnClickListenerMethod() method is tasked with setting the onClickListener for any and all buttons that might exist in the activity.
     * Currently, the activity has a single floating action button so this button's onClickListener is set in this activity.
     * The setObservableMethod() method is used to activate the Observer to observe changes in the LiveData object present in the ViewModel. */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        setOnClickListenerMethod();
        setObserverMethod();
    }

    /*The initializeDatabase() method is used to create an instance of the NotesDatabase class.
     * This single instance will be used for performing all the database transactions including the CRUD operations.
     * For creating an instance of this class, the application context is used.
     * I've assumed that using an application context will allow me to use the instance throughout the entirety of the application.*/
    private void initializeDatabase() {
        NotesDatabase.initializeDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    }

    /*The initializeViewModel() method is used for initializing the NotesActivityViewModel instance with the ViewModel class.*/
    private void initializeViewModel() {
        notesActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(NotesActivityViewModel.class);
    }

    /*The setObserverMethod() method is used simply for activating the observer.
     * This task is done at the Started state of the activity to allow it to start observing the changes in the LiveData as soon as the activity starts.
     * If there are any changes in the database, i.e., if it returns a List of NotesEntity objects, the list is sent to the setRecyclerViewMethod().*/
    private void setObserverMethod() {
        final Observer<List<NotesEntity>> observer = this::setRecyclerViewMethod;
        notesActivityViewModel.selectAllNotesMethod().observe(this, observer);
    }

    /*The setRecyclerViewMethod(...) is called when the observer observes a change in the LiveData.
     * Upon calling this method, the List of NotesEntity objects are passed into this method which promptly passes it to the RecyclerViewAdapter class.
     * Accordingly, the RecyclerView is populated with the required views and a new RecyclerView is displayed with the newly added notes.*/
    private void setRecyclerViewMethod(List<NotesEntity> notesEntityList) {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = activityNotesBinding.notesListRecyclerView;
        NotesAdapter notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(notesEntityList, this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
    }

    /*The setOnClickListenerMethod() is used to set the onClickListener to all the floating action buttons used in the activity.*/
    private void setOnClickListenerMethod() {
        activityNotesBinding.newNoteFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        activityNotesBinding.deleteAllNotesFloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    /*The onClick(...) method allows us to intercept all the clicks placed within this method.
     * Since, only a single view can be clicked in this activity, therefore, this method contains only a single if clause.
     * The if clause checks if the floating action button has been clicked or not.
     * If it has, an Intent object starts the AddEditActivity for the user to add a new note to the activity. */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == activityNotesBinding.newNoteFloatingActionButton) {
            Intent newNoteIntent = new Intent(NotesActivity.this, AddEditNoteActivity.class);
            newNoteIntent.putExtra("function", "insert");
            startActivity(newNoteIntent);
        }

        if (view == activityNotesBinding.deleteAllNotesFloatingActionButton) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = showAlertDialogMethod(
                    "delete_all",
                    getString(R.string.delete_all_notes_alert_title),
                    getString(R.string.delete_all_notes_alert_message));
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }

    /*The onNoteClicked(...) method here is an overridden method from the INotesActivity interface.
     * When a note is clicked in the RecyclerView, the clicked noteID is transferred to this method.
     * When this method is triggered, an Intent object is created to start the DisplayNoteActivity.java activity.
     * Within this object, the noteID of the clicked note is sent as an Integer extra to next activity.
     * Finally, the activity is started.*/
    @Override
    public void onNoteClicked(NotesEntity notesEntity) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NotesActivity.this, DisplayNoteActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.COLUMN_ID, notesEntity.getId());
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private AlertDialog showAlertDialogMethod(String function, String title, String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes_string, (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    if (Objects.equals(function, "exit"))
                        super.onBackPressed();

                    if (Objects.equals(function, "delete_all"))
                        notesActivityViewModel.deleteAllNotesMethod();
                })

                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no_string, (dialogInterface, i) -> dialogInterface.cancel());

        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = showAlertDialogMethod(
                "exit",
                getString(R.string.exit_title),
                getString(R.string.exit_message));

        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

**NotesAdapter.java**

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.R;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.databinding.IndividualItemsLayoutBinding;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.model.INotesActivity;
import com.arpansircar.java.notepadapplicationusingmvvm.room.NotesEntity;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * The NotesAdapter class is used for setting up the RecyclerView.
 * The class accepts a List of NotesEntity objects as the argument for it's constructor.
 * This list is used to populate the RecyclerView with newer objects.
 */
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesViewHolder> {

    private final List<NotesEntity> notesEntityList;
    private final INotesActivity iNotesActivity;

    public NotesAdapter(List<NotesEntity> notesEntityList, INotesActivity iNotesActivity) {
        this.notesEntityList = notesEntityList;
        this.iNotesActivity = iNotesActivity;
    }

    /*The onCreateViewHolder() method configures and returns the views for all the different objects present in the List.*/
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NotesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        IndividualItemsLayoutBinding individualItemsLayoutBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.individual_items_layout,
                parent,
                false
        );

        return new NotesViewHolder(individualItemsLayoutBinding, iNotesActivity);
    }

    /*The onBindViewHolder(...) method receives the views individually from the NotesViewHolder class.
     * This method then binds all these individual views to the list.*/
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NotesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NotesEntity currentNote = notesEntityList.get(position);
        holder.individualItemsLayoutBinding.setNoteDetails(currentNote);
    }

    /*The getItemCount() method simply returns the value denoting the size that our RecyclerView is supposed to be. */
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (notesEntityList != null) {
            return notesEntityList.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /*The NotesViewHolder class is used to hold each of the views for each of the objects present in the notesEntitiesList list.*/
    public class NotesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final IndividualItemsLayoutBinding individualItemsLayoutBinding;
        private final INotesActivity iNotesActivity;

        public NotesViewHolder(@NonNull IndividualItemsLayoutBinding individualItemsLayoutBinding, INotesActivity iNotesActivity) {
            super(individualItemsLayoutBinding.getRoot());
            this.individualItemsLayoutBinding = individualItemsLayoutBinding;
            individualItemsLayoutBinding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(this);
            this.iNotesActivity = iNotesActivity;
        }

        /*The onClick(...) method is used when we click a particular view present in the RecyclerView.
         * When the user clicks on a particular note, this method stores the object for that particular note from the list.
         * Next, the noteID is acquired from the object and is sent to the NotesActivity via the INotesActivity interface.*/
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            iNotesActivity.onNoteClicked(notesEntityList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you already have a method `getItemCount` which is part of your adapter, just use it to check the size of the content. a recyclerview is managed by an adapter, so you always have to ask/change the adapters data

Answer (score 1):

This may help :

```
 if(layoutManager.findViewByPosition(0)==null){
 that means recycler view is empty
}
```

please test it before to be sure,try it on a nonempty recycler view and make sure it does not give null when 0th position row is out of scene.if it gives nonnull value, we are good to go.let me know as well, if it works.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering. I tried out another method and it worked. Basically, I created a static instance of the MutableLiveData class and initialized it in the constructor. Next, I used the postValue method to post the size of the RecyclerView into the aforementioned instance. Finally, I created a static method in the same class and observed it in the NotesActivity class. Works.

Comment: great..did you try the one that I posted.. i was only skeptical if it would work if the first row is out of view...